# How can I change corner radius in material button toggle group?

Tags: android, xml, material-components-android, android-togglebutton, materialbutton

I want make Material Button Toggle Group Like this:
[all rounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cyhf.png)

But result is: [half rounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNlOB.png)

I've changed shapeAppearance (cornerSizeTopRight, ...) or cornerSize, but only the outer part of the buttons at both ends is rounded, and the inner button hasn't changed at the sharp edge.

I think the reason that never changed button's cornerSize is:

> MaterialButtonToggleGroup also overrides any shapeAppearance,
> shapeAppearanceOverlay, or cornerRadius attribute set on
> MaterialButton children such that only the left-most corners of the
> first child and the right-most corners of the last child retain their
> shape appearance or corner size.

Is there really no way to adjust the corner radius within the Material Button Toggle Group?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Custom View Class, which inherits MaterialButtonToggleGroup.

```
class MaterialButtonToggleGroupWithRadius
@JvmOverloads
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) 
: MaterialButtonToggleGroup(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val button = getChildAt(i) as MaterialButton
            if (button.visibility == GONE) {
                continue
            }
            val builder = button.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
            val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.button_toggle_group_radius)
            button.shapeAppearanceModel = builder.setTopLeftCornerSize(radius)
                .setBottomLeftCornerSize(radius)
                .setTopRightCornerSize(radius)
                .setBottomRightCornerSize(radius).build()
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this as View like MaterialButtonToggleGroup in the Layout xml file you want to use. Example:

```
<com.example.util.MaterialButtonToggleGroupWithRadius
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                ... />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                ... />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                ... />

</com.example.util.MaterialButtonToggleGroupWithRadius>
```